# appendix in APA 6 graphs and tables

Tags: tables, graphics, apa-style, apa6

I am using an APA 6 version for journal articles. I want to add large results tables at the end as well as full pages images. The APA splits the paper in two so the images and tables are located in each half (see image). How can I put them using the full page an overide the halves just for this part of the document?

I am usign the following code:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{rotating} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle    
THE TEXT ....
\appendix
\include{appendix}      
\end{document}
```

Many thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `sttools` bundle can help:

- `stfloats` allows to use  `[t]` as well as `[b]`placement specifiers  with the `figure*` or `table*` environments;
- `cuted` lets you place anything full pagewidth anywhere in the page with the `strip` environment  – in this case, as it's no more a float, you'll have to use `\captionof{table/figure}{...}` if you want captions.